# Which component of the Hextech Gunblade do I build first on Akali?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I am unable to get kills in the earlygame as Akali I like to build some spellvamp to stay in lane and farm a bit. But I am wondering which of the two components (Bilgewater Blade - Hextech Revolver) is the most cost effective to build first?

Answer (score 1):

Akali scales much better off of AP than AD, so if your goal is to maximize damage, revolver would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The Hextech Revolver allows you to stay in lane longer, the additional sustain from the spellvamp minimizing health lost and increasing the magic damage from your passive. Your skills also mostly scale with AP.

However, if you're dominating the lane, and already have a few kills in the lane, I'd say go for the Bilgewater Cutlass. It gives you some extra burst and CC to help you get even more kills.

Basically, it's very situational.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as they said, AP is the way to go with Akali, she can deal a lot of burst damage with AP.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most well-known competitive Akali player is Curse North America's top laner, Westrice.  When talking on stream about his Akali, he said that he went Gunblade.

That decision is supported by the top ranked Akali guide on solomid.net.  The [guide](http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=10075) says:

> Rush Hextech Revolver which will give a high sustain in lane, and a better farming ability, the AP amount is good as well.